# CNN Code not running in parallel in keras

Tags: python, keras, theano, cudnn

I am using a remote server that has a GPU Nvidia k40. The problem that I am facing is I am not sure if Cuda or cuDNN is installed on the remote machine. Even if it is installed I try to run my CNN model onto the machine. I get the following error:

> WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu0 is not available  (error: cuda unavailable)

Here is the complete screenshot of error:

[image]

1. I am using virtualenv.
2. Python Version 3.4
3. In .theanorc I have switched from device to gpu/cuda but both options don't work
4. Using theano as a backend to keras
5. I don't have sudo/root privileges to install any programs